# Back to back commands in mac terminal via java Runtime

Tags: java, process, terminal, runtime

Basically I have 2 commands I need to execute via a java program the way you would if you were just typing it into terminal.

so like

```
cd /Users/nameOfUser/Desktop/someFolder/someSubFolder
```

and then another command I want to execute within that directory. Currently I am doing this:

```
Process navigate = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd /Users/nameOfUser/Desktop/someFolder/someSubFolder");
Process doSomething = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("commandInThatDirectory");
```

Which doesn't work, it doesn't throw an exception but the second process doesn't seem to take place in the directory specified before it. I am new to processes and runtimes so please bear with me :P.

Is their a way to execute the commands back to back within the same instance of terminal or at least a format for 1 command where you can specify the directory for another command to take place in? I'm a linux user so I don't know mac terminal very well sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done something like this. you can run any command by by placing a semicolon between the commands.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder(
                "bash",
                "-c",
                "cd /Users/nameOfUser/Desktop/someFolder/someSubFolder;commandInThatDirectory");
        pb1.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb1.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, what is the "-c" for though? I understand bash tells it to open/use terminal but what does that c part do?